# Qt MYSQL not working on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, ubuntu

I'm trying to get MYSQL working via Qt on Ubuntu 15.10, however I am having an issue when loading the plugin. I'm using the latest Qt, downloaded from their website (Qt5.6.0) but I am getting the following error when launching the application:

```
Got keys from plugin meta data ("QPSQL7", "QPSQL")
loaded library "/home/rob/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so"
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/rob/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so" : "Cannot load library /home/rob/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so: (libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

The issue is, that `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` is not even part of the ubuntu 15.10 linux distribution, which uses instead `libmysqlclient_r.so.18`.

I've read somewhere that clearing Qt's plugin cache may help this, but I could not find out how to do that.

What steps should I take to fix this issue?